# Failed to load a remote .xml file from a variable

Tags: bash, ssh, xml

Trying to read .xml file from another server into a variable

```
test=$(ssh root@server "cat /dir/file.xml")
```

But when doing `echo $test`, it prints the .xml file in one-liner format.

Then trying to execute `xmllint` on this file,

```
xmllint $test
```

and getting the following error on each tag.

> warning: failed to load external entity "..."

Note: when doing the same procedure, but on local .xml file(without `ssh`), it's working and getting the expected result.

Any way to solve this? Or use `xmllint` tool remotely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your `$test` variable contains the **content** of the xml file, not its path.

Anyway, to show it keeping the spaces intact, quote the variable: `echo "$test"`.

To run a program getting the input from variable you can use stdin redirecton,  in this case it would be:

```
echo "$test" | xmllint -
```

You can also avoid using a variable:

```
ssh root@server "cat /dir/file.xml" | xmllint -
```

Finally, in bash, you can also use process substitution (see `man bash`):

```
xmllint <(ssh root@server "cat /dir/file.xml")
```